# Document Empty after uploading a SVG to AWS S3 bucket and trying to access to it via URL

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

So, i'm trying to upload my web images into a s3 bucket. I send them via HTTP Request to a lambda in AWS. It executes correctly and the image appears in my bucket, but when i tried to serve it in my frontend it doesn't load, and if i open the url in my browser i get this error:

***This page contains the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.***

My lambda is develop in nodejs v12, im using the aws-sdk ^2.765.0. And the code in the server side is this:

```
      let buf = new Buffer.from(image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""),"base64");

      let type = image.split(";")[0].split("/")[1];

      let params = {
        Bucket: process.env.BUCKET_IMAGE,
        Key: `${name.toUpperCase()}.${type.replace('+xml','')}`,
        Body: buf,
        ContentEncoding: "base64",
        ContentType: `image/${type}`,
        ACL: 'public-read'
      };

    s3.upload(params,function(err,resp){});
```

Any idea what could be wrong? The previous code works perfectly with any jpeg/png image.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the regex being used in the replace. If you debug this you will see that in the case of an svg, which will be "data:image/svg+xml..." the regex won't match and hence no replacements will be done.
The '+' sign there in the middle is not being covered by \w, which, as you pointed out does work for other extensions like jpeg...

```
image.replace(/^data:image\/[a-zA-Z+]+;base64,/, '')
```

would do the job in this case.
Once that is done, the buffer and encoding will work as expected.